# Using JFrame in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Here is my code, I am wondering why it prints "test" two times!? every command I add in "paintcomponent" performs 2 times. I would appreciate if you could help me please!?

```
              import java.awt.geom.*;// For Ellipse2D, etc.
              import java.util.*;
              import javax.swing.*; // For JPanel, etc.
              import java.io.*;
              import java.awt.*; // For Graphics, etc.
              import java.lang.Object;
              import java.util.Random; 

        public class hextopology extends JPanel {


        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("test");
              }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

          JFrame f = new JFrame();
          f.add(new hextopology());
          f.setSize(550,550);
          f.setVisible(true);
          f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            }
               }
```

Comment: It will print "test" every time the panel is painted. Try moving / resizing the frame, it will print "test" often.

Comment: What help do you need ? As Matthias has said that even if you resize it will print 'test' often and not only twice !

Comment: Thx for your kind reply. But in the first try "test" will comes out two times(with out resizing and moving)

Comment: Why exactly is this a problem? As long as `paintComponent()` is called at least once your stuff will be painted, so what's wrong?

Comment: @AndrewG  *"Why exactly is this a problem?"*  That is an *excellent* question.  This seems like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing resizing the window you are actually changing the window's properties, so your view elements should be painted again. That's why `paintComponent()` is getting called every time and as you have a print statement inside the method, it is printing as expected.

Comment: My problem is that even in the first try(without moving,re-sizing) it is getting called more than once!!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
f.setSize(550,550);
```

which is a resize, after the panel is created for the first time.

```
paintComponent
```

is called twice, because of this.

Comment: Exactly. `JFrames` go through many setup procedures when they are created. For example, they are set visible, possibly resized using the `setSize()` method, possibly packed. Along with a whole host of other stuff, this usually can cause them to paint themselves multiple times.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but without this "test" wont print at all!?

Comment: @user3180204 Ok, so maybe both of the calls to `paintComponent()` came from somewhere inside `setSize()`. I can't pretend that I know the inner-workings of a `JFrame`. But, to re-iterate my previous question in the comment to the question: What is the problem? Are you just curious as to why, or does this affect your code?

Comment: The problem is that when I extend the code it makes some problems for me ,and also as I used JFrame before and it has worked well I am so curious what is the matter in this code!

Comment: @user3180204 Move your println method to some other place and call it later, do not put it in paintComponent method.